# Why may the public ip address of an amazon ec2-instance become invalid after a certain while?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My ec2-instance works fine usually. But under seemingly random circumstances the public ipv4 address stops working. It does not work with PuTTY nor does my domain work via cloudflare which is pointing toward it.

Every time this problem occurs, I stopped and started the instance. As soon as I restart it and use the newly assigned public ipv4 address in PuTTY and everywhere else, it starts working. I tried using elastic ips but it still does not seem to work.

**Diagnostics**

I get an `Error 522: Connection timed out` from Cloudflare when I try to access my instance through the domain. I get successful responses from ping and traceroutes to my domains.

The system did not fail any status checks within this time and nor did it exceed any system resources. The CPU utilizations and Disk Read/Writes were at a minimum.

But when I try to ping my elastic-ip assigned to my instance I get a `Request timed out`. The traceroute results are also attached.

Hope this helps if more information is required please let me know in the comments

```
  1     2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     2 ms     1 ms     2 ms  172.16.33.137
  3     7 ms     1 ms     6 ms  103.12.172.217
  4     3 ms     3 ms     2 ms  103.12.172.237
  5    16 ms     3 ms     3 ms  103-16-155-109-noc.bsccl.com [103.16.155.109]
  6     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  103-16-152-30-noc.bsccl.com [103.16.152.30]
  7    13 ms    12 ms    11 ms  103-16-152-82-noc.bsccl.com [103.16.152.82]
  8    55 ms    54 ms    54 ms  xe2-2-1.singapore2.sin.seabone.net [93.186.133.28]
  9    55 ms    54 ms    57 ms  38895.sgw.equinix.com [27.111.228.87]
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12    54 ms    54 ms    53 ms  52.93.10.31
 13    59 ms    56 ms    54 ms  52.93.11.45
 14    57 ms    55 ms    58 ms  52.93.11.38
 15    56 ms    56 ms    56 ms  52.93.8.93
 16    87 ms    57 ms    54 ms  52.93.10.73
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

For the instance, the new packages that I installed after I started using this instance was `mod_ssl, httpd, openssl, telnet, mysql, mysql-server, tree, git` and other python dependencies. This is also a list of TCP ports that are being listened on along with the name of their daemons.

```
sudo netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3169/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2095                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2778/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2441/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35347               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2462/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2637/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2727/master
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      2441/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      2918/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      2637/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      2918/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::45125                    :::*                        LISTEN      2462/rpc.statd
```

Comment: Define "stops working". Is there an instance in your AWS Console with that IP, or does the IP not match the one you had on file? Are you sure the instance didn't just crash?

Comment: You don't get a new public IP if you restart an instance, but you do if you stop and start the instance. Please edit your post to be more precise, and include diagnostics such as ping, traceroute, etc, from both your PC outside AWS and another instance inside the VPC.

Comment: You're doing something wrong, but your question is not sufficiently detailed for us to work out what. Please edit the question to give all the diagnostics you do when the problem occurs. Elastic IPs and Public IPs both work fine, so the problem is a knowledge gap. We can help if you provide enough information.

Comment: I apologize for providing insufficient information. It would be amazing if you can guide me as to what I can do to provide more diagnostic information? @Tim

Comment: My previous comment gave you some hints. You sound like you'd also benefit from some training to get a good grounding in AWS - Linux Academy AWS Solution Architect Associate course is very good. I did it when I was starting with AWS and it helped immensely. Their pro and specialist courses are good too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Tim! Yes, I was struggling a bit to get the diagnostic information you mentioned above. I'll try to get into this course and look more into it to get that information as soon as I can. I'll give you a mention once I have something useful. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, @Tim. Please check out the new edits to the post. I added some diagnostic information and if you require anything else please let me know!

Comment: I would highly suspect an application or service running within your EC2 is affecting the networking port(s) of your OS. I have used EC2s for years with static and dynamic external IPs assigned and have never encountered an incident where the connectivity suddenly failed for no reason. Possibly including services/apps that you have specifically installed/configured/modified within the instance may be of value to us here to help identify the issue. Are you using any level of automation to deploy/configure the VM?

Comment: Are any of the services/applications within your instance altering security groups or ACLs? This would also contribute to connection failures.

Comment: I added some new information at the end according to what you said @Steven. I may have been wrong in estimating what you wanted exactly. It would be nice if you could guide me as to how I can provide more useful information. Thanks!

Comment: Read my suggestions again - ping / ssh in from an instance in the same VPC. Elastic IP ping - could be blocked by security group / NACL, you can definitely ping elastic IPs. CloudFlare filters some things out, use the IP of the server not the IP of CloudFlare.

Comment: @Tmdfx it is beyond difficult to predict what applications users install on their servers and how those applications may affect their servers performance. Thus I am uncertain as to what details to request. The list of services you report as installed should not have any impact on port 22. I would confirm in your configurations (I am not able to predict which ones to look for) anything that may be altering your SSH Server configs. - Ubuntu would be found in /etc/ssh/ssh(d)_config

Comment: As to the web server not responding via domain ... I would validate your HTTP Server configs. If Apache & Ubuntu /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ -OR- Fedora family /etc/httpd/...etc...   When using domain validation the ServerName needs to be identified. Possibly this will help with validating those settings: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html